# Turn headers on SQLite in Node

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Using `sqlite3` I'm connecting to my SQLite database, and I can get responses just fine, but I need the column headers included in the results.  Searching for hours now, I can find the '.headers on' command for the sqlite command line tool, but everything says dot commands are not available to Node in the sqlite3 library.  Is this just an impossibility?  If not, please!!! tell me how to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way of doing that. That's not really something I've ever seen in any database. I mean you can fetch them somehow, usually, by issuing some kind of query (depending on the database), but that is really rarely needed, only if you are building some kind of database management application usually. When you work with the data, you know the schema.

Comment: I know the schema; however, I'm returning a LOT of data to another application, and that application needs the headers (of which there are many) to be the first thing it receives.